# Strategies for Implementing a Disclaimer Screen in IOS

Tags: ios

In IOS you are not allowed to exit an app progrgrammatically (which I personally believe is ludicrous).

In my app I intend to display a disclaimer screen with some legal text and a agree and disagree buttons. When the user agrees, the app's main menu is presented. When they disagree, I would like the app to close. I would intend this to display only once when the app was first used and the disclaimer agreed to.

However, you can not close an app programatically because Apple don't like it. So

1) is this not a good reason for developers to need a close feature?

and

2) What usable and graceful alternative do I have?

Comment: If you can, put it into the EULA that you can submit to the AppStore, this will be displayed by Apple before the customer can even buy the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this not a good reason for developers to need a close feature?

Yes, but Apple does however **think different**.
The only thing you can do is accept and find the best alternative

> What usable and graceful alternative do I have?

Show:
[image: Disclaimer]

In case rejected show:
[image: Disclaimer]

Comment: This is what I went for in the end. On the disclaimer screen I displayed your second popup. So at least they cannot access the app if they disagree. Also if I decide to put a link to the disclaimer text  in the apps more tab,  the user cannot continue using until they agree with the disclaimer text.

Comment: If it was me, I probably wouldn't even have the Reject button, just the Accept button and leave it to the user to either Accept or Quit.

Comment: Some countries require both the `Reject` and `Accept` button, otherwise the disclaimer is not legally sound. This way users are forced to make an informed choice.

Comment: @Anne: They are still making a choice without the reject button.  Either accept or hit the home button to exit the app.  This is what Apple's HIG says to do....

Answer (score 2):

In the [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27), Apple recommends not to quit programmatically and offers two alternatives:

> **Don’t Quit Programmatically**
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
>   Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
>   choices.
>
> **Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction.** A screen provides feedback that reassures users that
>   there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control,
>   letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
>   continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
>   different application
>
> **If only some of your application's features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when people activate the feature.** Display
>   the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.

Therefore, I would go with something that meets the first option, and say "You must accept the terms of this agreement in order to contine."

Answer (score 0):

If, on a mobile App, this would be a useful case, it would have been implemented.

Generally, it is not a good practice to display screen at the beginning, because suddenly the user gets disappointed, because he doesn't get entertained a little bit from the beginning. On the other side, applications that require to be logged in do the same thing.

Suggests to handle your problem:

1. Present your screen at the beginning and if the user declines, you can show your app with no representative data and elements and maybe a box that says "sorry, you to precede, you have to accept my rules"
2. Do this agreement on a web-based service with login credentials and present a login screen a the beginning with the option to register a new account, where registering implements accepting the rules of using your service or app. This gives a more convenient approach, as it is done by many many services.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Another instance where this happens is in apps that need an internet connection. It does explain why some apps just continually display a warning dialogue in a constant loop, which I believe looks more like erroneous operation than a programatic exit. I believe the HIG should be modified to say an App can only be closed programaticaly as a  direct result of a clearly marked user interaction.

Comment: Further more if on dismiss the app does go to a secondary screen telling the user to press the home button what happens if they resume the app. The only way to do it would be to force the app to load the disclaimer screen again, putting the app on different screen than when sent to the back, thus negating the point of the resume feature.

Comment: This is not true. There are enough possibilities to present the disclaimer screen before the gets visible as well as when the app enters background calling methods. There are ways... You don't have to tell the user to tap the home button. He does it automatically, if he doesn't like it.